# npm cannot find index.html when launching REACT front end

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, mern

The problem occurs when I try to launch the front end of the app. I do this from within the frontend directory with the command: npm start. It is a MERN stack application. I am using git for version control. Others with access to the git can run npm start with no problems on their machines, so I think the problem could be related to the windows file or path systems, but haven't been able to find out.

The error given:

```
    Could not find a required file.
  Name: index.html
  Searched in: C:\Users\Liam\OneDrive\Desktop\COP4935\Project\DemocracyToken\public
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! frontend@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.    

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Liam\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-03T17_01_09_900Z-debug.log
```

npm appears to be trying to access the public directory from the project root (DemocracyToken) when the public directory is located in DemocracyToken/frontend/

I have tried:

rerunning npm install,
uninstalling and reinstalling node,
moving the location of the public folder,
and moving the location of index.html.

Here is the file structure of our app:

[image: screenshot of vs project directories]

Comment: Check the folder where you are running "npm start"
it should be inside /frontend

Comment: index.html is located in ./frontend/public. I get the same error whether I enter npm start from frontend or frontend/public.